# How to run rename shell command in android app (rooted)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, shell, command

I'm new to Android. I'm trying to run a shell command to rename a file in the system. I've got root access to it.

The shell command:

```
$ su
# mount -o remount,rw /system
# mv system/file.old system/file.new
```

I have tried this but doesn't work:

```
public void but1(View view) throws IOException{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o remount,rw /system");
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mv /system/file.old system/file.new");
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there is an error message or something like that... Why don't you share that along your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run more then one command using the same process, by writing the commands in the process's `OuputStream`. This way the commands will run in the same context that the `su` command is running. Something like:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw /system\n");
out.writeBytes("mv /system/file.old system/file.new\n");
out.writeBytes("exit\n");  
out.flush();
process.waitFor();
```

Comment: @cyanide No, `getOutputStream()` returns the output stream connected to the normal input of the subprocess. Output to the stream is piped into the standard input of the process represented by this Process object. See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream())

Answer (score 0):

You need each command to be in the same process as `su`, since the switch to root doesn't apply to your application, it applies to `su`, which completes before you get to `mount`.

Instead, try two exec's:

```
...exec("su -c mount -o remount,rw /system");
...exec("su -c mv /system/file.old system/file.new");
```

Also, be aware that I've seen some systems where the `mount -o remount,rw /system` would fail however `mount -o remount,rw /dev/<proper path here> /system` would succeed. The "proper path here" is different from one manufacturer to the next, but it can be programatically gathered.